# Putty, ssh, vps. Как переместить файлы?

Tags: ssh, vps, putty

Пытаюсь переместить папку и файлы с локального ПК на vps через

```
pscp 'C:/...' name@ip:/root
```

Но всегда выдает:

> C:/...: No such file or directory

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Попробуйте pscp -r для рекурсивного копирования.

Comment: Та же самая ошибка

Comment: Вы уверены, что у name есть право писать в /root? Вы бы привели бы реальную строку команды вместо точек и гаданий.